# Angular material2 Autocomplete binding with complex object list doesn't behave as it should

Tags: angular, angular-material

Autocomplete binding with a complex object doesn't behave as it should. I want to bind the autocomplete to complex object list and assign the selected complex object to another one but when I am doing it it is displaying [object object] in the autocomplete. I have also created the plunker to illustrate the issue

Currently It works only with array list of string. Instead of the binding list with plain string list bind it with the list of complex object.

I am using Angular Material v2.0.0-beta.3
[Plunker Link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4011)

Comment: In StackOverflow you should ask your question as succinct as possible, not copy over your bug request from the angular-material and paste it here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does work as described in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete). The key is to use `displayWith` and `(onSelect)` to handle object selection, as below.

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input type="text" mdInput [formControl]="searchControl" [mdAutocomplete]="usersComp"/>
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #usersComp="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="getDisplayFn()">
  <md-option *ngFor="let user of filteredOptions | async" [value]="user" (onSelect)="selected(user)">
    {{user.displayName}}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Component:

```
export class UserSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: any;
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

  searchControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      if (typeof data === 'string' && data.trim() !== '') {
        this.filter(data);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl.setValue(this.value ? this.value : '');
  }

  private filter(search: string) {
    this.api.get(`search/user/${search}`).subscribe(data => this.filteredOptions.next(data));
  }

  public getDisplayFn() {
     return (val) => this.display(val);
  }

  private display(user): string {
     //access component "this" here
     return user ? user.displayName : user;
  }

  public selected(user) {
    this.value = user;
    //send to parent or do whatever you want to do
    this.valueChange.emit(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: onSelect was never mentioned in the documentation but it works. displayWith got an issue. See GitHub repo of angular material they expect it as a parameter due to which you will loose context of this (which is a reference to ur component class). this reference starts to point function itself, therefore, you cannot access component functions and variables. There is a workaround which I have implemented in my solution which I will post soon. Having said that I will still accept ur solution as an answer coz u pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I have modified the answer so that `[displayWith]` returns function and then you have access to `this` component.

Comment: great job. The way I have implemented the displayWith is like [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)"